# How are radio buttons passed in a GET request?

Tags: html, ruby, radio-button, sinatra

How are radio buttons passed as parameters? I am using a Ruby Sinatra web server. How can I get the value of the selected radio button on the server side?

HTML

```
<form method="get" action="/register">
  <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="1" />
  <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="3" />
  <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="4" />
</form>
```

Ruby

```
get '/register' do
  params[:regRadio]??
end
```

Comment: In your example it will always send `regRadio=1` if either radio button is selected.  You probably want to use a distinct value for each radio button so that you can tell which one was actually selected.

Comment: My mistake, the radio buttons will have different values.

Comment: Did you try your code before asking?

Comment: Yes, trying to access params[:regRadio] results in 0 all the time.

Comment: Always 0, or actually nil? (i.e. are you calling `to_i` on `nil`, which gives you the illusion you have zero?)

Comment: Your right I was doing .to_i and getting 0. Checking again I see that the value of params[:regRadio] is nil. If a radio button is selected, should params[:regRadio] be the value?

Comment: Questions are marked as having an accepted answer based on whether you've clicked the tick next to an answer. There's no need to put "Question still unanswered" in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the method should be `post` instead of `get`. The rest seems fine. This works for me:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  <<-HTML
    <form method="post" action="/register">
      <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="1" />
      <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="2" />
      <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="3" />
      <input type="radio" name="regRadio" value="4" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
  HTML
end

post '/register' do
  "You selected #{params[:regRadio]}"
end
```

when you select the third item and hit "Register"

[image: form]

you will get the following result:

[image: result]

If this is not working for you, the problem is elsewhere. In this case, please show us your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a generic hint, as it is http, it should be the same in ruby.

The value is set on the name, which is regRadio. As both radio buttons have the value 1, there will always be the value 1 or nothing if it is not set. So one of it should be e.g. 2.